# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) as well as other errors

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I was trying to update OpenGL (A problem for another day, but if you can help on that front it also will be appreciated) when I started getting so problems
So I had done:

```
root@Friithian:/home/gunqqer# apt autoremove  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (= 2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 mesa-va-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
 mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>= 2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) but 2.4.83-1~16.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So then I did

```
root@Friithian:/home/gunqqer# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libdrm-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/60.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 232943 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) over (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1~16.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x) over (2.4.83-1~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.83-1~16.04.1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.89+git1712180630.831036~oibaf~x_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, I don't know what to do to fix this. If you need me to run a command and tell you the results I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is caused by default `dpkg` overwriting status. dpkg won't overwrite without your permission into shared folder. The workaround:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
and do:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hey this seems to have fixed my problem! Thank you so much, now on to fixing other things!

Comment: Please, accept my answer if that solved your question.